# using html agility to get the value of this node

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Trying to use html agility pack to get the value of the number of servings here

```
<span class="recipe-ingredients__header__toggles">
    <span class="ready-in-time__container">
        <span class="ready-in-time">3 h 30 m</span>
        <span class="icon--stats-clock"></span>
    </span>

<meta id="metaRecipeServings" itemprop="recipeYield" content="8">

<a href="" id="servings-button" popup-trigger="servingsSection">
    <span class="servings-count" ng-class="{'active': servingsSection_showing}"><span ng-bind="adjustedServings" class="ng-binding">8</span><span class="servings-count__desc" ng-class="{'active': servingsSection_showing}"> servings</span></span>

    <span class="icon--adjust-servings" ng-class="{'active': servingsSection_showing}"></span>
</a>

    <a href="" id="nutrition-button" popup-trigger="nutritionSection">
        <span class="calorie-count" ng-class="{'active': nutritionSection_showing}"><span>562</span> <span class="calorie-count__desc" ng-class="{'active': nutritionSection_showing}"> cals</span></span>
        <span class="icon--nutrition-info" ng-class="{'active': nutritionSection_showing}"></span>
    </a>
```

Specifically I'm looking at the tag

```
 <span ng-bind="adjustedServings">
```

that has the value "8". I've gotten every other value just fine here but can't seem to figure this one out. I just want the integer 8 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SelectSingleNode("//span[@ng-bind='adjustedServings']").InnerText
```

Should do the trick. If you have multiple of these `span`s use `SelectNodes` instead, use it in a `foreach` and access `InnerText` on the nodes separately.

*Didn't try to compile, if you run into error, I'll edit it*

Comment: this does get the node but always the inner text is always == "" for some reason.

Comment: Strange...does `<meta id="metaRecipeServings" itemprop="recipeYield" content="8">` always contain the same number or is this just a coincidence. You could get the number from that, as it is an attribute it may be more likely. Also: Did you check the node in the debugger yet? Is the InnerText property the same there? Or you try to set the InnerText property to something else, read it in again and check if it's maybe a problem with the node itself.